# Is it safe to remove google's "unused_argv" from forked python projects?

Tags: python

On projects that google share on the web, they use:

def main(unused_argv):

[(see example)](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/im2txt/im2txt/train.py)
, where `unused_argv` is never used. I couldn't find why do they do it and it annoys me to have warnings on my code.

Is it safe to remove this parameter?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In that case it's presumably, because the tf.app.run function expects the main function to have a positional argument

This is the code that will call your main function: [Source](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py)

```
from tensorflow.python.platform import flags

def run(main=None):
  f = flags.FLAGS
  flags_passthrough = f._parse_flags()
  main = main or sys.modules['__main__'].main
sys.exit(main(sys.argv[:1] + flags_passthrough))
```

Comment: For future readers, I used `_ = unused_argv` in order to keep the argument and suppress the warning.